# Custom message in Twillio outbound call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

By reading the Twilio tutorial, I am able to place outbound calls. But, can you point out a tutorial where I can find information that teaches how to place a outbound call in Twilio using a custom message (.i.e Good morning my friend)? On Twilio website there are several tutorials showing how to place calls, but I wasnt able to find any showing how to customize the message spoken when the call is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [place an outbound call with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) you provide a URL parameter that points to some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) that tells Twilio what to do with the call next.

You can customise the message by customising the TwiML that you respond with. You need to return the TwiML you want. For your example you can return:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Good morning my friend</Say>
</Response>
```

If you want to return dynamic content then you need to generate this TwiML from a web application.

There are a whole bunch of [tutorials for building custom voice applications with Twilio in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?order_by=-popularity_rank&filter-product=voice).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: It helped. Can you point out a document describing how I can upload a .mp3 message to be executed when placing an outgoing call (if it is supported by Twillio)?

Comment: You can upload mp3s to your [assets section of the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/assets/public) and then use [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) instead of `<Say>` with the URL to play the mp3 on the phone call.

Answer (score 0):

Just for new upcoming who want to know how to customize Twilio calls message, you can use `twiml` key in the passed array to create method, a full snippet is below:

```php
$twiml_msg = '<Response>
<Say voice="woman" language="en-US">
    Hello NAME_HERE,
    Thank you for your interest in our product!
    Regards
</Say>
</Response>';

(new Client($account_sid, $auth_token))
    ->calls
    ->create(  
        $to_number,
        $twilio_number,
        array(
            "twiml" => $twiml_msg
        )
    );
```